How can I use the Facebook Graph API with Python manually?
Since there is no official support of the Graph API in Python, and I don't want to use unofficial libraries, can someone tell me how to write the code to use it in Python?
I tried to search for ways to write code in Python but the results I'm getting are unofficial libraries. I'll have to write the code manually.

Facebook themselves provide a "Business SDK", https://github.com/facebook/facebook-python-business-sdk - but you'd have to check if that allows to perform all the operations you need. If you still want / need to write your own code - the API is HTTP-based, so you basically don't need much more than something that can make HTTP requests ...

if API has documentation then it may have examples in Python using requests or urrlib. Eventually it may have examples for tool curl and there is CurlConverter which can convert curl to many languages - and it can generate code for requests or urllib in Python. But sometimes it may create small mistakes.

if you would test API using tool Postman then it should have function to generate code for requests in Python
